# SQL: trying to choose one options as an default when it has duplicated (oracle)

Tags: oracle, duplicates, default-value

I have some problem in SQL

My data is like this

| Company | Report date | source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 20071231 | 01 |
| 01 | 20081231 | 01 |
| 01 | 20081231 | 02 |
| 02 | 20071231 | 02 |
| 02 | 20081231 | 02 |
| 03 | 20071231 | 01 |
| 03 | 20071231 | 02 |

I want to choose '01' like an default in source column. But if not, then I want to choose source '02'

The result what I want is like this

| Company | Report date | source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 20071231 | 01 |
| 01 | 20081231 | 01 |
| 02 | 20071231 | 02 |
| 02 | 20081231 | 02 |
| 03 | 20071231 | 01 |

Thanks

```sql
select company
     , report date
     , source
from   (
        select *,
         count(*) over
           (partition by company, report date, source) as b
from the table
where b > 1
```

I cannot figure it out this result is true or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps sorting rows per (company and date) by (source), so that 01 (if it exists) comes before 02 or any other value, and then extract rows that ranked as the highest?

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (company, report_date, source) as
  2    (select '01', 20071231, '01' from dual union all
  3     select '01', 20081231, '01' from dual union all
  4     select '01', 20081231, '02' from dual union all
  5     select '02', 20071231, '02' from dual union all
  6     select '02', 20081231, '02' from dual union all
  7     select '03', 20071231, '01' from dual union all
  8     select '03', 20071231, '02' from dual
  9    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
 10  temp as
 11    (select company, report_date, source,
 12       row_number() over (partition by company, report_date order by source) rn
 13     from test
 14    )
 15  select company, report_date, source
 16  from temp
 17  where rn = 1;

COMPANY    REPORT_DATE SOURCE
---------- ----------- ----------
01            20071231 01
01            20081231 01
02            20071231 02
02            20081231 02
03            20071231 01

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you need all row with minimal value of `source` for respective `company`.

```sql
select
    company,
    "report date",
    source
from
    mytable t1
where
    source = (
        select min(source)
        from mytable t2
        where t1.company = t2.company
    )
```

If you want only those, where `source` is minimal, but either `01` or `02` you can add condition:

```sql
select
    company,
    report_date,
    source
from
    mytable t1
where
    source = (
        select min(source)
        from mytable t2
        where t1.company = t2.company
    )
and source in ('01', '02')
```